# How to getQueueUrl as an array with an array of queueName?

Tags: java, scala, aws-sdk

Is there a way to get an array response for val `getQueueUrlResponse` on `SQSClient.getQueueUrl` method call with an array of `sqsName`s? I have many `sqsNames` and I'd like to batch the request into one request, I'd like to avoid hitting `SQSClient` multiple times.

```
val getQueueUrlResponse = sqsClient.getQueueUrl(GetQueueUrlRequest.builder.queueName(sqsName).build)
```

So if I have 10 elements in Array `sqsName`, I'd like 10 elements in the `getQueueUrlResponse` val. I only see one value per call, but I may not be understanding something since I'm new to java/scala. TIA!

[getQueueUrl doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueUrl.html)

Also: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sqs/SqsClient.html#getQueueUrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetQueueUrl` request supports just one SQS queueName at a time. Therefore there's also no way to get an array back.

As an alternative you could check if it's feasible to do a single `ListQueues` request instead. That supports filtering by a common queue name prefix (or returns everything, depending on the size potentially in multiple pages).